# Module handlers in python

Tags: python

What are module handlers in python?
I want to know how are they used in a python script.
I was making a colour scheme for a text editor when I came across this term. Is there any difference between module handler in python and other languages?

Comment: Any particular context?

Comment: I did a Google search on `"module handler" python` and it returns no relevant result. I don't think such term exists in Python.

Comment: look at this color scheme script https://github.com/trusktr/gedit-color-schemes/blob/master/gtksourceview-3.0/styles/Bespin.xml and find this line *style name="python:module-handler" foreground="#5ea6ea"/>*

Comment: That would most probably mean "handler for module coloring", which is specific to the code you are working on, not in general Python. It is just a name (as the field name suggests) to refer to a specific part of the code which should be colored, just like it's defining "special variables" on every language.
You need to check with the other part of the code to see what does it refer to.

Comment: it is obviously a name for part of language syntax. Change it to a unique and distinct color (like magenta), open few files in gedit with this scheme, and you probably find it pretty quick ;) My blind guess would be that this is for names under which given module is imported